# How to install Ubuntu alongside Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: live-usb, mac

How do I install Ubuntu alongside Mac OS Catalina?

I installed [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#osx) and created a bootable Ubuntu 22 v running.

But when I choose Installation Type, I do not get the option to
*"Install Ubuntu alongside MAC OSX"*, but only *"Install Ubuntu (Will erase data on partition...)"*

I created the bootable USB stick with [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher#download-etcher).

Have I missed something? What should I do?

Comment: Which model of Mac are you trying to install Ubuntu onto? Is your Mac partition encrypted?

Comment: Ubuntu 22?   Don't forget 22 & 22.04 are different systems, Ubuntu Core 22 being a *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server intended for *headless* cloud or IoT use.  You don't normally install a *headless* server system in dualboot, it's normally used with desktop systems & whilst Desktop is available for 22.04 & 22.10 - it's not available for 22.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked in a while, but the last time I did, Ubuntu didn't offer very flexible options for resizing macOS partitions at install time. Thus, you may need to use macOS utilities to shrink the macOS partition *before* booting the Ubuntu installer, or provide a blank disk for the Ubuntu installation. Even then, you may need to use the "Something Else" option to manually create partition(s) for Ubuntu.